# Removing old rock hard adhesive from concrete floor

Tags: flooring

i have removed the old ceramic tile that was put down on top of linoleum. It came up easier because of that but I now am being told that the old rock hard glue or backing has to come up. I have tried everything that people have suggested but no luck. Not even a few inches after an hour. Its like its part of the concrete. If it is that hard do I really need to remove it?.. Frustrated .

Comment: You did not mention the steps you tried. Some adhesive’s are water based and a towel soaked with water will soften it in some cases,   in other cases grinding is needed. You do want to remove any ridges and bumps or the new flooring will be affected.

Comment: What kind of flooring will be installed ?

Comment: If it absolutely has to go, I'd look at using an oscillating [Multi-tool](https://fein.com/en_uk/oscillating-multi-tool/) with a chisel bit. Otherwise, could you apply a screed?

Comment: if it's rock hard, use a floor grinder.